# Data insertion in SQL server with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to upload a dataframe in SQL server using pandas (to_sql) function, I get the below error

> [SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast
>   specification (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I checked for variables' names and types and they are exactly the same in the SQL database and pandas dataframe.

How can I fix this?
Thanks

```
df.to_sql(raw_table, connDB, if_exists='append', index=False  )
```

Comment: If you can create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you have better chances of getting a quick solution. Try providing the SQL Server table script (You can right click on table and copy). And provide df.head(). Also mention the different versions of the tools you are using.

Answer (score -2):

> plz try this , this code use to juypter note book and SQL workbench

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

mydata = pd.read_csv("E:\\Hourly_Format\\upload.csv")

engine = create_engine("mysql://root:admin@localhost/pythondb", pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)


mydata.to_sql(name='emp',con=engine,if_exists='append', index=False)
```

jupyter :-
[image]

workbench :-

[image]

Comment: This solution (if it works) it is for Mysql, and PO is having a problem with SQL server, they are different RDMS